# Quickblox API errors when using Guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm using "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.1" and Laravel 4.2 
I'm trying to make a post call to quickblox but return me 422 error. This is my code in the controller:

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $sessionGuzzle = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.quickblox.com/session.json',['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json' , 'QuickBlox-REST-API-Version'=>'0.1.0'],'json' => $jsonBody]);
    $response = $client->send($sessionGuzzle);
    dd($response->json());
```

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (422)
>
> Client error: 422

Answer (score 0):

The 422 is the HTTP status code - Unprocessable Entity.

Looks like the quickblox API is rejecting your call because your either sending the wrong headers or body.

Try changing `'json' => $jsonBody` to `'body' => $jsonBody` and make sure `$jsonBody` is a JSON encoded string.

Comment: nothing append changing 'json' in 'body' that's what i have inside the $jsonBody :
{"application_id":"22337","auth_key":"UcUiGsRmOZ-Fq-J","timestamp":"1446051576","nonce":"380128471","signature":"7707eeb02b00bgsd5g7f57sgc225de2358611"}

Comment: currently I'm using another library, anlutro\cURL, with guzzle i can't make any request.. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Quickblox documentation on [errors](http://quickblox.com/developers/Errors#Errors_Unprocessable_Entity) your 422 error occurs when

> User with login that has already been taken

According to the Quickblox documentation on [authentication](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization) the timestamp that is provided must be +/- 10 minutes of NTP.

Comment: The problem is related with Guzzle currently i'm using another curl library for laravel and it's working, so i think is not a problem related with the data used for the request..

Comment: If you enable the debug option, is the request that you are sending, what you believe you are sending, or what was being sent while using v2?